# if var='value' then in Zsh: Is it really a valid syntax without semicolon?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, zsh, ksh

The following code works on Zsh 5.8 that I tried, **despite the missing semicolon**. **But is it really a valid Zsh syntax?**

```
#!/bin/zsh
if var='value' then
   echo 'then'
fi
```

Without an assignation that causes `` parse error near `fi' ``:

```
#!/bin/zsh
if true then
   echo 'then'
fi
```

**The correct syntax, with a semicolon:**

```
#!/bin/zsh
if true; then
   echo 'then'
fi
```

**Both of code without semicolon are incorrect in sh, Bash and Ksh 93.**

I'm confused that Zsh accepts `if ... then` in the same line without semicolon only in some circumstances. An assignation in the place of the condition seems a particular case.
This documentation doesn't precise when a semicolon is necessary or not:
https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#index-if-construct

In fact **my concern is about Ksh**. When I try with a real implementation of Ksh 93 there is an error: `` syntax error at line ...: `fi' unexpected ``.
But when I run Zsh with `emulate ksh`, that works. I guess that works only because it is not really Ksh but Zsh, and that it is always an error in real Ksh. **Is there somewhere precise documentation that confirm that?**

Here my tries in sh, Ksh, Bash and Zsh, with the corresponding outputs:
https://bitbucket.org/OPiMedia/hellanguages/src/master/comparative/shell/if_then/

Comment: The behaviour of other shells isn't always very relevant for zsh, which has a lot of ["alternate" forms for complex commands](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#Alternate-Forms-For-Complex-Commands). For example, `for i in 1 2 3; echo $i` will output `1`, `2` and `3` in zsh, but other shells will expect the `do ... done` part to follow.

Comment: "(But Ksh emulated by Zsh has the same behavior than Zsh.)" ... does that mean ksh emulated by zsh has the same behaviour _as_ zsh, or _unlike_ zsh?

Comment: @muru, I understand that Zsh has different behaviors. But it is not clear for me when a semicolon is necessary or not.
I modified the question to precise my concern.

Comment: Necessary for what? Are you trying to write portable code that works across shells, or are you only aiming to write code for zsh?

Comment: `if true then` is always syntactically incorrect. In this case a semicolon is *necessary*.
I want to know in which circumstances the semicolon is not necessary in Zsh.
But my main concern is about Ksh. I want to know if in some cases the semicolon is not necessary in Ksh. Because I have some code written in Ksh but running in Ksh emulated by Zsh. I suspect that a semicolon is always necessary in Ksh, even if that works without semicolon in particular cases in Ksh emulated by Zsh.
I know, this is a mess. ;-) Difficult to be clear.

Answer (score 1):

After an assignment, a command is allowed. For instance:

```
LC_ALL=C grep foo file
```

is valid in any Bourne-like or `rc`-like or `fish` shell. And means running `/path/to/grep` with `grep`, `foo` and `file` in `argv[]` and `LC_ALL=C` in `envp[]` (shells being before all interfaces to the `execve(file, argv[], envp[])` system call).

So it's not totally surprising that the parser accepts and recognises that `then` token as the `then` keyword of the `if`/`fi` construct, since `then` is otherwise expected wherever a command would be expected.

You'll also find that you can do:

```
if then else (echo foo) fi
```

For the same reasons.

I wouldn't rely on it though as it's undocumented and could change in the future.

In `if true then` or `if echo then`, `then` is obviously an argument for `true`/`echo`, and the `if` construct is missing its `then`.

In effect, the fact that `then` is recognised as a keyword after that `var='value'` is not allowed by POSIX (in the `sh` syntax).

The POSIX requirement that in:

```
var=value keyword
```

`keyword` not be recognised as a keyword but as the name of a command to execute is not overly useful though as no-one would name a command after a POSIX shell keyword.

For instance, POSIX requires that:

```
var=value if true
```

Run the `if` command if available with `true` as argument and `var=value` in its environment.

```
$ ln -s /bin/printenv bin/if
$ a=bar bash -c 'if a'
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
$ bash -c 'a=foo if a'
foo
$ zsh -c 'a=foo if a'
zsh:1: parse error near `if'
```

zsh not following that requirement (even in `sh` emulation) is unlikely to cause problems in practice. I'd expect in the unlikely event anyone wanted to call a command named `if`¹, they would write it `'if'` or `"if"` or `\if` to avoid it being mistaken for the `if` keyword, whether it's preceded by `var=value` and/or a redirection or not.

```
$ a=bar bash -c '"if" a'
bar
$ bash -c 'a=foo "if" a'
foo
```

```
$ a=bar zsh -c '"if" a'
bar
$ zsh -c 'a=foo "if" a'
foo
```

---

As a side note, POSIX requires:

```
if true; then if true; then echo x; fi fi
```

(without a newline or semicolon between those two `fi`s) to work, a bizarre requirement but that just specifies what ksh88 did (inherited from the Bourne shell) which is the implementation which the POSIX specification is mostly based on.

`zsh` doesn't honour that requirement, it doesn't allow that extra word after `fi`.

`if (true) then (echo x) fi` works in most shells including `zsh`, but IIRC in that case, the behaviour is unspecified by POSIX.

---

<sup>¹ Actually, as a historical anecdote, early Unices had a command called `if`. That was before the Bourne shell or C shell which came later with their own `if` construct. That was then removed as redundant with those constructs.</sup>